# oh my zsh - compdef git plugin - why _git needed

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

Please see [this line](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/7cea8475fbf8e1ba9e665e7740e35182c57bfb6f/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh#L95) in the git.plugin.zsh file:

```
compdef _git gdv=git-diff
```

In the [zsh user compdef tutorial](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org), the `compdef` for referencing an existing command is explained like this:

```
compdef cmd1=cmd2
```

The obvious question: why is `_git` needed?

Comment: Come on, I want to accept an answer.